# How to create a profile template in 2012 R2

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, user-profile

We are going through a phase of trying to minimise unnecessary IT admin work and we're goign to create AD template profiles for departmental roles, not sure how you go about doing this though, is it a case of just making a regular user and then just "Copying" that user each time we have someone that fits the template?

Comment: Are you trying to create a User **Profile** template that has default user desktop configuration settings in it, or a User **account** template in Active Directory that has default group membership and other user data in it?

Comment: Yes, typically you create and configure a template user then disable that user. When you have a new user that needs that template, you copy it and create a new user and enable the new account.